# Want to replace a variable with another new one

Tags: reactjs

I want to replace a variable in an object array with another name,

```
let arr={name:'ash', id:2}
```

I want to replace it as `arr = {newname:'ash', id:2}`

Comment: `arr.newname = arr.name;
delete arr.name;`

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1.

```
let name = arr.name
arr = {...arr, name: null, newname:name}
```

2. 

You can use `omit` function from `lodash` library, and this option is better. Here is docimentation of [omit function](https://lodash.com/docs/#omit)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr={name:'ash', id:2}

let newname = arr.name;
delete arr.name

arr['newname'] = newname

console.log(arr)
```

You can use  a variable to store the value of name ,then use Object operator delete the key of name